# Angular routing not working in Chrome

Tags: angularjs

Im trying out AngularJS and have been watching Dan Wahlin's youtube video on it and can't get the routing to work in Chrome or IE. Everything works fine in FireFox, but that's it. It just gives a blank page. 
Anybody knows what might be wrong?

Here's the code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <!-- Placeholder for views-->
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

foo.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/view1',{templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html',controller: 'SimpleController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2',{templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html',controller: 'SimpleController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
});
var controllers = {};
controllers.SimpleController = function($scope){
    $scope.customers = [
        {name:'John Doe',city:'Phoenix'},
        {name:'Jane Doe',city:'New York'},
        {name:'Terrence Winter',city:'Los Angeles'},
        {name:'Barack Obama',city:'Washington DC'}
    ];
    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
        $scope.customers.push(
            {
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name, 
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city
            });
    };
}
demoApp.controller(controllers);
```

View1.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>View 1</h3>
    Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name"/>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'name'"> {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    Customer Name: <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
    <br>
    Customer City: <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>
    <br>
    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <br>
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

View2.html

```
<div class="container">
<h3>View 2</h3>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="city"/>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:'city'"> {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tested it locally, it could be chrome preventing local html files of the views to be loaded. Do you have any errors in the console ?

Comment: Ah, didnt think of checking the console.. Get this error message:
"Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." for View1.html..  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You should open the page in a webserver. Upload it somewhere or use a local server (like MAMP for example) to open it. OTherwise chrome won't let you load local files for security reasons.

Comment: Great, got it to work by using Visual Studio instead of notepad. Thank you :)

Comment: Btw, Grunt - http://gruntjs.com/ is a nice tool if you want to set up a testing server quickly :)

Answer (score 3):

Chrome does not allow this as templates are loaded via AJAX. You can resolve this issue by setting up a simple http server using npm.

Go to your project folder in the nodejs command prompt. And type

**npm install http-server -g**

This will install http server on your machine.

Then start your server using the command

**http-server**

Now, run your files using the ip and port on which your server has started and there you go! Routing works in Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your angular module as below:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',["ngRoute"]);
```